# Bootstrap.less doesn't load bootstrap stuff

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, less, bower

Bootstrap.css works for me but bootstrap.less doesn't.  I'm not really sure why, I triple checked my folder to see if all the files for .less were in there and they were.  Isn't bootstrap.less the same thing as bootstrap.css but more orderly?  For clarification, this:

WORKS:

```
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">

<title>Backbone Tutorial Blogroll App</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Backbone Tutorial Blogroll App</h1>


<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

DOESNT WORK :( :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">

<title>Backbone Tutorial Blogroll App</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Backbone Tutorial Blogroll App</h1>


<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Browsers do not understand Less files directly, Less code has to be translated to CSS first. Read some [Less tutorials](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Less+tutorials) or simply start at http://lesscss.org/ to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS is a slightly different stylesheet language from CSS. Many projects write their stylesheets in LESS, and use a processor to convert it to CSS before it is used in the browser.

You don't need to include `bootstrap.less`, only `bootstrap.css`, because the CSS file was generated from the LESS file at some point for you already.

To clarify, the browser cannot interpret any LESS, only CSS.